# watchOS Remote Notifications With Custom Buttons

Tags: ios, watchos-2

I have tried and tried to get a custom button to appear when an remote notification is received.  My dynamic controller is indeed loading but only the Dismiss button shows.  Here's my PushNotificationPayload.apns file:

```
{
"aps": {
    "alert": {
        "body": "Hi! How you doing? This is a test message. Press 'Reply' button to reply. Thanks!",
        "title": "Petya"
    },
    "category": "myCategory"
},

"WatchKit Simulator Actions": [
   {
   "title": "Reply",
   "identifier": "replyPressed"
   }
]
```

}

And here is my code in NotificationController.swift:

```
override func didReceiveRemoteNotification(remoteNotification: [NSObject : AnyObject], withCompletion completionHandler: ((WKUserNotificationInterfaceType) -> Void)) {
    if let remoteaps:NSDictionary = remoteNotification["aps"] as? NSDictionary{
        print(remoteaps)
        if remoteaps.objectForKey("alert") != nil {
            let title = remoteaps.valueForKey("alert") as? String
            self.alertLabel.setText(title)
        }
    }
    completionHandler(.Custom)
}
```

From everything I've read that should work but the Reply button doesn't show up.  What am I missing?